# Undefined control sequence error - chapter

Tags: errors, undefined

My file is compiling, but I get an error at every section start.

For example, I start a new chapter:

```
\chapter{ENERGY MARKET FORECAST} 
\label{chap:demand}
\section{World energy outlook}
```

I get the error ''undefined control sequence'' to the left side of the \section{World energy outlook}. My document class:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,twoside,titlepage]{book}
```

I have used exactly the same code before without any issues. The only difference is that I have removed a lot of content, nothing else.

In addition to this, the pdf-version show this for some reason:

[image]

So ''2.1 World energy outlook'' comes twice. This is really odd as it hasn't happened before.

Do you have any suggestions as to why?

Edit2:
I am sorry for making this hard. I have removed the code and also the parts that were repeated. Thank you for that. Below is a screenshot of the error message:

[image]

Comment: Please make a full but minimal example that others can copy and test as is. That makes it a **lot** easier to help

Comment: That is not a **minimal** or **full** example. There is no document body. Please also remove irrelevant settings/packages.

Comment: Note that you are using a lot of package that you shouldn't be using. Plus, in most cases `hyperref` should be the very last package loaded.

Comment: Erh: the only error I get is from the missing `}` on  `\newcommand{\clearemptydoublepage`. Always look at the first error, not accumulative errrors

Comment: you have posted a lot of code but not an example of a section heading that makes an error, nor shown the error message from the log file (which would show which command is undefined) Please post a small but complete example that generates the error you are asking about.

Comment: your preamble is far more complictaed than you need, why specify amsmath three times for example, or tikz twice?